# how to write this view

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables

**customer**

```
customerid    
customername
```

**orders**

```
customerid
orderid
isopen [true/false]
```

How can i create a view that will contain the following :

customer name , total orders , total orders where isopen column ==true

*Update**

```
create view CustomerOrders as
select c.id CustomerID, 
       max(c.customername) CustomerName,
       count(o.order_id) CustomerOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.isopen = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OpenOrders
from customer c
left join orders o on c.id = o.customerid
group by c.id
```

Thank you all 
mark please correct your answer so i can mark you

Comment: How do you intend to correlate the two tables? Does the customer table have a customerid column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
create view CustomerOrders as
select c.customerid CustomerID, 
       max(c.customername) CustomerName,
       count(o.order_id) CustomerOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.isopen = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OpenOrders
from customer c
left join orders o on c.customerid = o.customerid
group by c.id
```

(Assumes that you want to include customers with no orders - change the left join to an inner join if you want to include only customers with orders.)

Comment: almost there 
i get error  about sum  Operand datatype bit is invalis for sum operator

Comment: create view CustomerOrders as
select c.id CustomerID, 
       max(c.customername) CustomerName,
       count(o.order_id) CustomerOrders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.isopen = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OpenOrders
from customer c
left join orders o on c.id = o.customerid
group by c.idTrue1

Comment: Amended as per comment. I don't have access to MySQL at the moment, but thought I had successfully summed bit datatype columns in the past - perhaps this varies between versions of MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS 
  SELECT customername, count(orderid) as total_orders 
   FROM customer c
   LEFT JOIN orders o ON ( c.id = o.customerid AND o.isopen = TRUE)
  GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below given syntax

```
 Create View OpenOrders AS
       SELECT CUSTOMERNAME, count(ORDERID) FROM CUSTOMER INNER JOIN ORDERS
                CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ORDERS.CUSTOMERID
       WHERE ORDERS.ISOPEN =1;
```

Comment: this won't show the number of orders for each customer, and also won't show the customers that don't have any orders

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it untill you have the customerid attribute along with customername. they will not link otherwise

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this, depending on the specifics of the table definitions (which you don't present):

```
create view viewname as
 select c.customername, count(o.*) as totalorders
  from customer c, orders o
   where c.customerid = o.customerid and o.isopen
```